# Uniformly sampling the solution space for points where the free termini of two rays, anchored at 3-space points, can intersect

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry

I have two rays, one of length $L_1$ and one of length $L_2$.  I anchor these rays, each at one end, on the 3-space points $p_1$ and $p_2$.  Assuming that the Euclidean distance between $p_1$ and $p_2$ is $\leq (L_1+L_2)$, what solution space defines the points where these rays can be oriented to touch at their free ends?  How might I sample uniformly from this solution space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample points uniformly from the circle of intersection between the two spheres of radii
$L_1$ and $L_2$ centered on $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively:

     [image: Two spheres]

     <sub>(Image from [Mathalino.com](http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/solid-mensuration-solid-geometry/sphere).)</sub>